# How to keep a specific rhythm during sets?

Tags: strength-training, sets, reps

I would like to keep a consistent rhythm during  sets and reps (Like 4 seconds down, hold 1s, 4 s up, pause 1s).

Any tips for how to do this? What would ideal cues look/sound like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting is generally best for keeping rhythm when lifting. You can say the numbers out loud, murmur them, shout or grunt them, or just count in your head.

Answer (score 0):

To be very precise with your tempo, one suggestion would be to use this [tempo trainer](http://www.finisinc.com/tempo-trainer-pro.html) or a [metronome app](http://www.bulletproofmusician.com/five-best-metronome-apps/).

You can set them for different tempos which makes the counting easier.